# gSOAP files has stray @

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gsoap, wsse

I am compiling a program using [gSOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSOAP) with [`g++`](https://www.cprogramming.com/g++.html) and [qmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake). After hours of working around it, I got to this error from the compiler:

```
/usr/share/gsoap/import/ds.h:89:2: error: stray ‘@’ in program
  @char*     Id;
  ^
```

Taking a look in the files in `/usr/share/gsoap/import`, I can see a lot of `@`s in them:

A part of `wsse.h`:

```cpp
/// Element "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd":Reference of complexType "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd":ReferenceType.
/// @brief This element defines a security token reference
/// Imported element _wsse__Reference from typemap WS/WS-typemap.dat.
typedef struct _wsse__Reference
{    @char*                    URI;
    @char*                    ValueType;
} _wsse__Reference;
```

What are those `@` in the code? I think there isn't any such thing in C++.

There are also other weird things in it. Another compile error is:

```
/usr/share/gsoap/import/ds.h:289: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     char* /*base64*/                     PgenCounter                    1; ///< Required element.
                                          ^
```

Taking a look at the source file, there are a lot of such things in struct definitions:

```cpp
/// "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":DSAKeyValueType is a complexType.
struct ds__DSAKeyValueType
{
/// Element G of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     G                              0;    ///< Optional element.
/// Element Y of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     Y                              1;    ///< Required element.
/// Element J of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     J                              0;    ///< Optional element.
/// Element P of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     P                              1;    ///< Required element.
/// Element Q of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     Q                              1;    ///< Required element.
/// Element Seed of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     Seed                           1;    ///< Required element.
/// Element PgenCounter of type "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":CryptoBinary.
    char* /*base64*/                     PgenCounter                    1;    ///< Required element.
};
```

I don't know how to interpret the numbers after the property name.

---

### Summary of answer:

As mpromonet mentioned, the files in `/usr/share/gsoup/import` like `ds.h` and `wsse.h` are not C/C++ codes and should not be compiled with a C/C++ compiler. It can be understood from the comment in their headers:

> Generated with: wsdl2h -cuxy -o ds.h -t WS/WS-typemap.dat WS/ds.xsd

Instead, they should be handed to the tool coming with `gsoap` called `soapcpp2` like this:

```
soapcpp2 -I/usr/share/gsoap/import /usr/share/gsoap/import/ds.h
```

The problem then was that I was already compiling another file called `onvif.h` with soapcpp2 and the tool can't handle two files together. Then (again, thanks to mpromonent), it turns out that importing the second file, `wsse.h`, in the original file `onvif.h`, can fix the problem. In other words, adding the following line to the `onvif.h` file:

```
#import "wsse.h"
```

At first it appears that there are not much information in the web to me, but in the meantime, I found this guide which is pretty helpful:

*[Getting Started with gSOAP](http://www.genivia.com/dev.html)*

Comment: You are correct in that this is nether valid C, nor valid C++. I suspect it's input for some custom preprocessor of theirs.

Comment: Can someone define a preprocessor starting with @?

Comment: It might be used for machine generation of documentation or something.

Comment: Well, it should be commented then, because GCC should know not to deal with it. Like what is in Doxygen: /// @param: ...

Comment: Appending answer section to your question is confusing.

Comment: Emm... I thought it would be hard to follow all the comments. Is it better to just remove what I've added to the question, or there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/usr/share/gsoap/import/ds.h` file is generated by `wsdl2h`. In comments you should see something like:

```
Generated with:
wsdl2h -cuxy -o ds.h -t WS/WS-typemap.dat WS/ds.xsd
```

This is not a C/C++ include. It should be processed by the gSOAP tool `soapcpp2`:

```
soapcpp2 -I/usr/share/gsoap/import /usr/share/gsoap/import/ds.h
```

This will generate include and source files that you should compile with your project.

In order to use [wsse](http://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html) plugin, you should append to the file generated with *wsdl2h*:

```cpp
#import "wsse.h"
```

Comment: So, I was wrong including `wsse.h` file. But one step before doing that, I'm trying to use gsoap for onvif, and using wsdl2 file I generate a file called `onvif.h` and compile it with soapcpp2. Some files are generated then but they don't include important definitions, and give errors like:

Comment: /usr/share/gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.h:218: error: use of enum 'wsse__FaultcodeEnum' without previous declaration
     int soap_wsse_fault(struct soap *soap, enum wsse__FaultcodeEnum fault, const char *detail);
                                                 ^

Comment: To avoid this, I tried including wsse.h which defines the missing enum and after reading your answer I was trying to give the files together to soapcpp2 but it seems that can't handle two input files because passing the second one makes it not to generate several outputs as before.

Comment: From [wsse](http://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html), it seems you should include `#import "wsse.h"` in the generated `onvif.h`...